# Even positioned numbers are escaped unfortunatly python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function:

```
def fun(l):
    for i in l:
     if len(i)==10:
      l.append('+91 {} {}'.format(i[:5],i[5:]))
      l.remove(i)
     if len(i)==11:
      j=list(''.join(i))
      j.remove(i[0])
      l.append('+91 {} {}'.format(''.join(j[:5]),''.join(j[5:])))
      l.remove(i)
     if len(i)==12:
      j=list(''.join(i))
      j.remove(i[0])
      j.remove(i[1])
      l.append('+91 {} {}'.format(''.join(j[:5]),''.join(j[5:])))
      l.remove(i)
     if len(i)==13:
      j=list(''.join(i))
      j.remove(i[0])
      j.remove(i[1])
      j.remove(i[2])
      l.append('+91 {} {}'.format(''.join(j[:5]),''.join(j[5:])))
      l.remove(i)
  return l
```

say l=['9195969878','07895462130','919875641230']

I am getting the output as

['+91 91959 69878','7895462130','+91 98756 41230']

But i have suppose to get the output as:
    ['+91 91959 69878','+91 78954 62130,'+91 98756 41230']

Actually this function is escaping all that is positioned even no in 'l' list. Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the list `l` as you go - I would suggest to create a new list and add things to this list.  Is there a reason you want to mutate in place?

If you are intent on mutating in place, why not just do something like this?

```
l[index] = '+91 {} {}'.format(i[:5],i[5:])
```

Also, here is the first google result for "python phone number library": https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers as it may be of use to you. (Never used it, am not the maintainer.)

Comment: Great , i will try and let you know

Comment: A small mistake here. Your `i` refers to a index then an list element.

Comment: yes , u cant replace with l[i]='+91 {} {}'.format(i[:5],i[5:]) but you can add it to a new list . Now its working fine . Tnxs

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you're mutating the list while iterating over it. In this particular case, this caused the loop to skip some items, as you deleted items that were earlier. In other Python versions it might trigger an error. But you're returning your result, so I don't see why you're mutating the list at all.

Secondly your code does some roundabout things, in particular `''.join(i)` which is absolutely redundant (it literally rebuilds the same string), and series of remove() calls which almost certainly don't do what you expect. If you remove the first item from [1,2,3], the list becomes [2,3], and if you follow that by removing the second item (index 1) you end up with [2]. This is the same sort of issue your for loop has with the other remove.

I would also restructure the code a bit to avoid code duplication. I get something like:

```
def fun(l):
    return ['+91 {} {}'.format(i[-10:-5],i[-5:])
            for i in l]
```

This never alters `l`, makes one single pass, and joins all the different length behaviours by observing that we're using parts at a fixed distance from the end. There is one caveat: other lengths aren't handled separately. I don't know if those occur, or how you actually want them handled (the old code would leave them as is). We can easily enough specify other behaviour:

```
def fun(l):
    return ['+91 {} {}'.format(i[-10:-5],i[-5:]) if 10<=len(i)<=13
            else i
            for i in l]
```

This still doesn't reproduce the behaviour that reformatted numbers were appended at the end, but I'm not sure you really wanted that. It made little sense for the loop to process its own output in the first place.